# Error while starting python windows service executable

Tags: python, windows-services

I am trying to make a python windows service as instructed from  
https://www.thepythoncorner.com/2018/08/how-to-create-a-windows-service-in-python/  The service installed directly from python console runs just fine.
but when I make the executable file (for server without python environment) by auto-py-to-exe and install via command prompt it installs but gave this error

```
windows_service.exe install
Installing service TestService
Changing service configuration
service Updated

windows_service.exe start
Starting service TestService
Error starting service : The service did not respond to the start or control request in timely fashion

windows_service.exe debug


AttributeError: module "servicemanager" has no attribute 'debugging'
```

This error only occurs when .py script converted into .exe

Comment: Did you find solution to this? I have exact same problem

Comment: Can u find the answer for it? I need it very urgently. I am stuck in this for last 10 days.

Answer (score 0):

I remove module servicemanager in pip and edit and run pyinstaller solve the problem

```
pip uninstall servicemanager
```