# pywin32 cannot debug if project is packed into .exe

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, windows-services

I have my project installed as a windows service and everything worked smoothly. I had some errors with using venv and pywin32, but eventually figuret that out. [Stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59047849/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-win32serviceutil)

However when I use pyinstaller to make onefile executable from it problems start occuring.

I use following command to create executable:

```
[Path_to_my_venv_pyinstaller] --onefile --hidden-import win32timezone myservice.py
```

Then I am executing it from cmd with `install` arg, service is installed.

However next step, executing it with `start` arg fails. Error message:

```
Starting service [Service_Name]
Error starting service: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.
```

So I tried debugging it with ``debug``` argument. It works normally, when I install service without executable, from source files. When service is installed from executable I am getting following error.

```
Debugging service [Service_Name] - press Ctrl+C to stop.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[Service]\[Service_Folder]\service.py", line 48, in <module>
  File "lib\site-packages\win32\lib\win32serviceutil.py", line 640, in HandleCommandLine
  File "lib\site-packages\win32\lib\win32serviceutil.py", line 461, in DebugService
AttributeError: module 'servicemanager' has no attribute 'Debugging'
[14252] Failed to execute script service
```

I found similar topic on stack, unanswered, [link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59467171/error-while-starting-python-windows-service-executable). So the problem indeed lays in installing service from pyinstaller executable.

I have no idea, how to track error on this, Event Viewer does not display anything more than i could see from console.

Is there other way to debug a service?